# Livebindings BindScope Notification

Tags: delphi, data-binding, delphi-xe2, livebindings

To get started with live bindings i am currently writing some demo code. But at one point i have a problem where i don't find any documentation on.

I have a form with multiple TEdit's and want to bind them with an TBindScope to properties of an object. I setup the BindScope and the BindingList and everything works for the moment when i do BindExpression1.Active := true;

But now i change the properties of the object and want to notify the BindingList about an update.

Here is the Problem. I cant find any way to notify the BindingList, so it updates the values.
But if i do a BindExpression1.Evaluate it synchronises the values.

I tried using

- BindingList.Notify(BindScope, 'Object.Property')
- BindingList.Notify(BindScope, 'Object')
- BindingList.Notify(Object, 'Property');
- BindingList.Notify(BindScope, 'Property');
- BindingList.Notify(BindScope, 'Active');

Nothing seems to work for the notification.

P.S. : I know that in this case the BindScope is not necessarely needed. But since its demo code for understanding, i would like to know how it works with the BindScope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the source code of [`TCustomBindScope.GetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Bind.Components.TCustomBindScope.GetValue) for details on how the scope is resolved.

1. [`Component`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Bind.Components.TBindScope.Component) is used if assigned, otherwise
2. [`DataObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.Bind.Components.TCustomBindScope.DataObject) is used if assigned, otherwise
3. [`Owner`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Owner) is used

So the simplest solution is probably to leave the `Component` property (of your TBindScope component) unassigned and make your `Object` a property of the owner form.

Comment: I think that the problem I described is not caused by a problem in resolving the BindScope. Because else i think the BindExpression1.Evaluate would not work. The question is more how do i have to notify when the value changed.

Comment: @Marks That sounds right, try to post the complete compilable code to reproduce the problem.